# Converting string into hex representation

Tags: python, formatting

I am looking for a good way to convert a string into a hex string.

For example:

- `'\x01\x25\x89'` -> `'0x012589'`
- `'\x25\x01\x00\x89'` -> `'0x25010089'`

Here is what I have come up with:

```
def to_hex(input_str):
    new_str = '0x'

    for char in input_str:
        new_str += '{:02X}'.format(ord(char))

    return new_str
```

It seems like there is probably a better way to do this that I haven't been able to find yet.

Comment: Use regex to remove the `\x`s?

Comment: the `\x` isn't really part of the string. it's to show the value of the raw bytes

Answer (score 6):

You want the [binascii](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) module.

```
>>> binascii.hexlify('\x01\x25\x89')
'012589'
>>> binascii.hexlify('\x25\x01\x00\x89')
'25010089'
```

Answer (score 5):

Just encode to hex:

```
In [5]: s= "\x01\x25\x89"

In [6]: s.encode("hex")
Out[6]: '012589'

In [7]: s = "\x25\x01\x00\x89"
In [8]: s.encode("hex")
Out[8]: '25010089'
```

Comment: This works well for python 2 and I like that it doesn't require a module. The answer by [Chris](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34661666/4538876) will work for python 2 and 3 though.

Comment: @JakeGreen, neither would actually work for python3 without an encode, if you wanted a solution for both 2 and 3 `codecs.encode(s,  "hex")` but again you will have to encode  s

Comment: you are right. I was thinking more about my specific use case in my previous comment and I never mentioned what my use case is. I have been using `struct` to pack some data which returns type bytes in python 3 and not a string, so binascii works for my use case in both versions of python. Sorry about that. Thanks for the good info though.