# Converting data from sqlite into hex string notation in python

Tags: python, string, sqlite, unicode

I have a 64 bit address that i want to store in a sqlite db column. The column is of type VARCHAR. This is how i store the data to the db. The sql is done in python using the cursor object c.

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO SENSORS(XBEE_ID) VALUES('\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x40\xe9\x21\x9d')")
```

I want to then read that address from the database and pass it to a function that will then send the data to some xbees. I am using a xbee library that accepts the address in the form:

```
dest_addr = '\x00\x13\xa2\x00\x40\xe9\x21\x93'
xbee.tx(dest_addr_long = dest_addr ,data=newState)
```

when i use

```
repr(dest_addr)
```

I get

```
 '\x00\x13\xa2\x00@\xe9!\x93'
```

also

```
type(dest_addr)
```

gives

```
<type 'str'>
```

But when I read the data from the database, and store to a variable,I get an error "the data provided for 'dest_addr_long' was not 8 bytes long.

```
 addr_long = c.fetchall()
 addr_long2 = addr_long([0][0])
 xbee.tx(dest_addr_long = addr_long2,data=newState)
```

when i read the data from the db it is of type unicode.

```
repr(send_addr[0][0])
```

which returns

```
u'\\x00\\x13\\xa2\\x00\\x40\\xe9\\x21\\x93'
```

and

```
<type 'unicode'>
```

, so i tried this - 
[Convert a Unicode string to a string in Python (containing extra symbols)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-a-unicode-string-to-a-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols)
but it did not work.

I am basically looking for the opposite of this . [Converting string into hex representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34661563/converting-string-into-hex-representation)

**so my questions, 
is my method right for storing the data in the db?

how can I manipulate the data so that I can get it in the string type that is required for the function?**

Comment: Show a concrete example (`repr()` format) of what you are currently receiving and what you actually want, like:  got `u'\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x40\xe9\x21\x9d'` (a Unicode string) and want `'0013A20040e9219D'` (a byte string), or maybe `'\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x40\xe9\x21\x9d'` (a byte string).  Also, what Python version are you using?

Comment: SQL does not use backslash escapes. Is your first code SQL or Python?

Comment: Hey, I I am using python 2.7.3.

Comment: Which XBee library are you using and what does the documentation say about the function signature (i.e. argument types) of `xbee.tx(dest_addr_long, data)`?

Comment: i am using this library https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XBee . In the library it specifies 8 bytes long for dest_addr_long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after some research and help from a friend,  you can simply use

```
send_addr[0][0].decode("string_escape")
```